# quickblox cordova switch camera during call

Tags: cordova, camera, quickblox

Is it possible to switch camera from front to back and vice versa during call in quickblox cordova.

If then please help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the camera is not supported. You can switch the camera, but you need to restore your call.
We will add this feature in the future.

Comment: Hi Vlad Lukhanin, may i know when camera switching functionality can be included in framework sdk.